# Content Background and Colors are not preserving while Transforming Docx file to Html in Java using Apache Tika

Tags: java, html, apache, apache-tika

Apache Tika is not preserving content background settings and colours. Where am I wrong?

Have written something like below, Any Suggestions?

```
{
  InputStream input = TikaInputStream.get(new File("abc.docx"));
  Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
  try {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
    TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-16");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
    handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    handler.setResult(new StreamResult(sw));
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.add(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html;charset=utf-16");
    metadata.add(Metadata.CONTENT_ENCODING, "charset=utf-16");
    parser.parse(input, new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(handler), metadata, new ParseContext());
    String xml = sw.toString();
    System.out.print("TIKA : " + xml);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("xyz.html")));
    bw.write(xml);
    bw.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    input.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Apache Tika only aims to give you "semantically meaningful" xhtml. You probably want to use one of the Apache POI specific converters for high fidelity

Comment: could you specify any one convertor from Apache POI ?